# Programmatically count grouped data using logic rules and string

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a grouped data frame which I want to summarise into "count of values less than x, y, z by group". I can manually generate the wide dataframe I want using code similar to this below

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1337)

df <- data.frame(cbind(group = seq(1:5), num = sample(x = 1:400, size = 100, replace = T)))

manual <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(less_than_50 = sum(num < 50),
            less_than_100 = sum(num < 100),
            less_than_150 = sum(num < 150))
```

However, I'd like to be able to define a list of "less thans" and generate these columns by referring to a list. I've done something similar in the past, though using enframe(quantile()) to generate a long list of quantiles before pivoting

```
pc <- c(0.1, 0.5, 0.9)

quantiles <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(enframe(quantile(num, pc))) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = group,
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  )
```

But I don't know / understand the way to define a custom function within the enframe(). Ideally I'd like to apply this in something like the code below (though this obviously doesn't work), with or without the pivot step, in order to get back to the same output as "manual"

```
levels <- c(50, 100, 150)

programmatic <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(cols = ("less_than", x), num < levels) %>% 
  pivot...
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please edit your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for others to help?

Comment: I think `dplyr::across` will give you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1337)

df <- data.frame(cbind(group = seq(1:5), num = sample(x = 1:400, size = 100, replace = T)))

less_than <- function(x) {
  
  df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(less_than_ = sum(num < x)) %>%
    rename_with(~ str_c(., x), .cols = -group)
}

levels <- c(50, 100, 150)

map_dfr(levels, less_than) |> 
  group_by(group) |> 
  summarise(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   group less_than_50 less_than_100 less_than_150
#>   <int>        <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1     1            4             5            10
#> 2     2            2             2             5
#> 3     3            2             6            11
#> 4     4            4             5             5
#> 5     5            1             7             9

# Manual result for comparison
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(less_than_50 = sum(num < 50),
            less_than_100 = sum(num < 100),
            less_than_150 = sum(num < 150))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   group less_than_50 less_than_100 less_than_150
#>   <int>        <int>         <int>         <int>
#> 1     1            4             5            10
#> 2     2            2             2             5
#> 3     3            2             6            11
#> 4     4            4             5             5
#> 5     5            1             7             9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Out of interest, why use the base R pipe after the map function?

Comment: I switched my keyboard short-cut (shift-command-M) to the native pipe a few weeks ago. I try to be consistent with the one the OP used, but get the base one by default if I forget to paste `%>%`. There's no reason not to use `%>%`.